# How to know if my certificate uses sha256 or sha384, without converting it first string and running find on it?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I need to know what kind of hash algorithm my certificate has. I only figured out how to do it my converting the the loaded certificate to a string and running find on it. For example:

```cpp
BIO *certbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
X509 *certificate;
BIO_read_filename(certbio, "/etc/some.crt")
certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(certbio, NULL, 0, NULL)

int pkey_nid = OBJ_obj2nid(certificate->cert_info->signature->algorithm);
if (pkey_nid != NID_undef)
{
    std::string algorithm = OBJ_nid2ln(pkey_nid);
    algorithm.toLower();

    if (algorithm.find("sha256") != std::string::npos)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if(algorithm.find("sha384") != std::string::npos)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to know whether my certificate uses `sha256` or `sha384`, etc?

Can I check my`pkey_nid` value against a openssl constant as in the following example?

```cpp
...
int pkey_nid = OBJ_obj2nid(certificate->cert_info->signature->algorithm);

if (pkey_nid == NID_sha1WithRSAEncryption)
{
    // ...
}
else if(pkey_nid == NID_shaWithRSAEncryption)
{
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

I tried find a constant for `sha256`, but the only ones I could find were things like `NID_shaWithRSAEncryption` and `NID_sha1WithRSAEncryption`, but no `NID_sha256WithRSAEncryption`:

1. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/1c0eede9827b0962f1d752fa4ab5d436fa039da4/crypto/objects/objects.pl#L175
2. https://svn.python.org/projects/external/openssl-0.9.8y/inc64/openssl/objects.h

Is there a documentation which maps these names as `NID_shaWithRSAEncryption` to the algorithm as `sha256` or `sha384`, so I could use these constants as in my second example?

Or the only why to figure out if my certificate uses `sha256` is by converting the certificate algorithm to string and run a find on it as I did on my first example?

Related:

1. [In OpenSSL, given a certificate, how can I get a string representation of the signature algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632670/in-openssl-given-a-certificate-how-can-i-get-a-string-representation-of-the-si)
2. https://man.openbsd.org/X509_get0_signature.3
3. [Check signature for x509 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264747/check-signature-for-x509-certificate)
4. [How do I print a fingerprint (sha256 bytes) using colon notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662366/how-do-i-print-a-fingerprint-sha256-bytes-using-colon-notation)
5. [How can I see if the certificate is SHA384?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228951/how-can-i-see-if-the-certificate-is-sha384)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code, does not look openssl have an interface to get a certificate type, just a string value it gets from a global variable:

```cpp
// File: openssl-1.0.2m/crypto/objects/obj_dat.c
const char *OBJ_nid2ln(int n)
{
    ADDED_OBJ ad, *adp;
    ASN1_OBJECT ob;

    if ((n >= 0) && (n < NUM_NID)) {
        if ((n != NID_undef) && (nid_objs[n].nid == NID_undef)) {
            OBJerr(OBJ_F_OBJ_NID2LN, OBJ_R_UNKNOWN_NID);
            return (NULL);
        }
        return (nid_objs[n].ln);
    } else if (added == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    else {
        ad.type = ADDED_NID;
        ad.obj = &ob;
        ob.nid = n;
        adp = lh_ADDED_OBJ_retrieve(added, &ad);
        if (adp != NULL)
            return (adp->obj->ln);
        else {
            OBJerr(OBJ_F_OBJ_NID2LN, OBJ_R_UNKNOWN_NID);
            return (NULL);
        }
    }
}
```